# Confusion about a boundary condition (steady heat conduction)

Tags: boundary-conditions, heat-conduction

Given a composite material composed of two materials each having different thermal conductivities and heat flux vectors. This leads us to write the two properties as position dependent. One thing I don't understand is taking the temperatures of both materials to be equal at the interface when writing the boundary condition. And also, the normal heat flux vectors to be equal at the interface between the two materials. The writer in the paper `An Introduction to Periodic Homogenization` mentions that it's for the sake of continuity. It isn't clear to me.

[image]

Comment: Any physical quantity can have one and only one value at a fixed point. There is no possibility for temperature to jump from a° to b° at a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One thing I don't understand is taking the temperatures of both materials to be equal at the interface when writing the boundary condition.

Our heat transfer models allow any point to have a single temperature only. This is consistent with kinetic theory and observation; since heat transfer increases with an increasing temperature difference, two distinct temperatures at a single point would constitute an infinite temperature gradient, which would force an enormous heat flow until a single temperature is obtained.

> And also, the normal heat flux vectors to be equal at the interface between the two materials.

This arises from conservation of energy—where else would the energy go?

Comment: Thank you. I understand now the issue of temperature, but can you please explain me how the normal heat flux is related to conservation of energy?

Comment: This arises from applying the [First Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics) to a system defined by the interface. Any energy entering must be stored or must exit, and apparently there's no mechanism for the interface mentioned by the author to store energy.

Comment: Thank you. So, the interface allows only for passing the heat flux. But, why is the heat flux leaving material 1 equal to the heat flux leaving material 2?

Comment: It’s not. The heat flux leaving one material equals the heat flux *entering* the other material. We know this because there are no minus signs; we equate the heat fluxes moving in a certain direction at the interface. If this seems confusing, try sketching the flux vectors.

Comment: I'm trying to sketch them. There's no minus sign, but n1 (the normal of material 1) is opposite in direction to n2 (normal of material 2), because the normal at interface is outward. I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: For the paper to be correct, positive $q_1$ and $q_2$ must also point in opposite directions.

Comment: Thank you. So, what does q1,x = - q2,x mean?

Comment: Ah! They have negative signs to mean that what's lost on one side is gained by the other side? I think it's clear now. Thank you! Just asyou said